# tailwind tabs how to scroll if too many tabs exist

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using tailwind tabs in my application.

I need to be able to scroll left/right if there are too many tabs to show.

Currently if there are too many tabs they just cut off and the user is not able to see them. When it resizes down for mobile it changes so it's a dropdown so it's not an issue there, just on the bigger sizes.

Here is the section of code that contains the tabs:

```
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 lg:col-span-3 ">
            <div className="p-6">
              {/* Hero section */}
              <div className="relative">
                <div className="relative  sm:overflow-hidden">
                  <div className="pb-3">
                    <div className="sm:hidden">
                      <label htmlFor="tabs" className="sr-only">
                        Select a tab
                      </label>
                      {/* Use an "onChange" listener to redirect the user to the selected tab URL. */}
                      <select
                        id="tabs"
                        name="tabs"
                        className="block w-full pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md"
                        defaultValue={
                          tabs.find((tab) => tab?.current)?.name || "default"
                        }
                      >
                        {tabs.map((tab) => (
                          <option key={tab.name}>{tab.name}</option>
                        ))}
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hidden sm:block">
                      <div className="border-b border-gray-200">
                        <nav
                          className="-mb-px flex space-x-8"
                          aria-label="Tabs"
                        >
                          {tabs.map((tab) => (
                            <a
                              key={tab.name}
                              href="#"
                              className={classNames(
                                tab.current
                                  ? "border-indigo-500 text-indigo-600"
                                  : "border-transparent text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-200",
                                "whitespace-nowrap flex py-4 px-1 border-b-2 font-medium text-sm"
                              )}
                              aria-current={tab.current ? "page" : undefined}
                            >
                              {tab.name}
                              {tab.count ? (
                                <span
                                  className={classNames(
                                    tab.current
                                      ? "bg-indigo-100 text-indigo-600"
                                      : "bg-gray-100 text-gray-900",
                                    "hidden ml-3 py-0.5 px-2.5 rounded-full text-xs font-medium md:inline-block"
                                  )}
                                >
                                  {tab.count}
                                </span>
                              ) : null}
                            </a>
                          ))}
                        </nav>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: you may want to use `overflow-auto` instead of `overflow-hidden` to enable scrolling when necessary

Comment: I tried this but it seemed to do nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow-x-auto` class to a `<nav>` element. This is the parent for your tabs

```html
<nav
  className="-mb-px flex space-x-8 overflow-x-auto"
  aria-label="Tabs"
>
```

[HTML demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jU5QCmCW8x)